# Dynamic friction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, home-experiment

In my house, we are debating whether when you scrub the floor it is easier or more difficult to drag a piece of furniture. My floor is made of marble, who's right?

Comment: Why don't you do an experiment and find out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dynamic friction the object you drag gets stuck on the surface you drag over, kind of like velcro but much smaller. I would imagine that if you polish the floor this surface becomes more smooth at a small scale and you would lower the coefficient of static friction.